# How to set Unity Canvas to display like it will on Lenovo Phab 2 Pro

Tags: android, canvas, unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

It is more a Unity / Android question. I am making an Google Tango application but I don't manage to configure my Unity Editor and the canvas to display a real overview of how it will actually look like on the Lenovo Phab 2 Pro device.

Do you know how should I setup the canvas scaler to fix that ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the `UI Canvas` incorrect on the device when you build the app? Or are you talking about the `Game view` inside your Unity editor?

Comment: My problem is that both in scene view and game mode in the editor, the canva doesn't have at all the same proportion as in the app. So I have to build my app and go back and forth from device to editor everytime I do a modification if I want to see how it will really look like in the end.

Comment: Well two things: you could resize your `Game` window in Unity in order to get the desired resolution(by entering the exact resolution like:800:400). Secondly (I advise more) to make anchor points for all of your UI, this will attach things to corners or edges so it looks correct even if you don't see it. Also make sure in the canvas settings you set the `UI scale mode` to: _Scale with screen resolution_. Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer Hristo. I have indeed already set "Scale with screen resolution" with parameters 2560*1440 which appear to be the screen resolution of the Lenovo. I 'll try to use anchors everywhere and see how it goes.